# Как анализировать неструктурированные данные в R

Tags: логирование, r

C чего начать анализ? Как из неструктурированных данных получить таблицу с данными? Как можно сгруппировать неструктурированные данные по конкретному признаку?

Данные типа веб-логов:

```
192.153.142.144 - - [30/Jun/2016:09:29:25 +0300] "GET /hls_online/ng_1.m3u8 HTTP/1.1" 200 309 "http://121.0.0.1:8080/itso/operator/screen2.html?testing=3" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"
192.153.142.144 - - [30/Jun/2016:09:29:25 +0300] "GET /hls_online/ng_2.m3u8 HTTP/1.1" 200 309 "http://121.0.0.1:8080/itso/operator/screen2.html?testing=3" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"
192.153.142.132 - - [30/Jun/2016:09:29:25 +0300] "GET /hls_online/ng_1-24785.ts HTTP/1.1" 404 168 "http://121.0.0.1:8080/itso/operator/screen2.html?testing=3" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"
```

В результате я хочу получить Shiny-приложение, где увижу, кто и с какого конкретного ip-адреса и на какую страницу сайта получал доступ. Например, из выпадающего списка можно было бы выбрать ip-адрес, дату, и сразу же построится график действий пользователя, куда тот заходил по часам.

Comment: Уточните, что именно вы хотите получить в результате?

Comment: То, что есть сейчас - это вектор строк. Нужно написать регулярные выражения для извлечения нужных данных и с их помощью получить таблицу (например, с 3 столбцами: ip, дата, url). См. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215789/extract-a-substring-in-r-according-to-a-pattern, например. Но Shiny-приложение в результате парсинга не получится, его еще предстоит написать :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я выше не совсем правильно регулярки посоветовал использовать, увидев соответствующий тег в вопросе. Все гораздо проще:

```
df <- read.table("df.txt", sep = " ", header = F)
df
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть данные вполне структурированные и с ними можно сразу же начинать работать.

Comment: это интересно с момента "сразу же начинать работать". Каким образом можно проанализировать подобные данные? Кроме группировки по типу сообщения и по ip-адресу ничего в голову не приходит.

Comment: Так это от поставленных задач зависит, по-всякому можно.